# Error when deploying to OpenShift JBoss 7

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x, openshift

I've been trying to deploy a Java application to an OpenShift JBoss 7 server and since I'm using a newer version of Hibernate (4.3.4) than the one that comes with JBoss 7 (4.0.1) I've included the newer jars into:

- .openshift\config\modules\org\hibernate\main
- .openshift\config\modules\org\hibernate\envers

This two folders follow the original structure in the JBoss server modules folder and have the same files (just an upgraded version).

Whenever I push the code to the repo OpenShift starts compiling it and once done (this is successfully done) it tries to start up the JBoss instance failing and giving this error (took it out through SSH):

```
2014/04/19 01:20:27,944 ERROR  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool --
27) Failed to define class org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform
in Module "org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" from local module loader @d2093b (root
s: /var/lib/openshift/5351ba0d4g57n47nf978fm4f/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/
config/modules,/var/lib/openshift/5351ba0d4g57n47nf978fm4f/jbossas/modules): jav
a.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/jboss/as/jpa/hibernate4/JBossAppServerJt
aPlatform (Module "org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" from local module loader @d2093
b (roots: /var/lib/openshift/5351ba0d4g57n47nf978fm4f/app-root/runtime/repo/.ope
nshift/config/modules,/var/lib/openshift/5351ba0d4g57n47nf978fm4f/jbossas/module
s))
```

What am I missing here? I've been googling around but couldn't find anything like this...
Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems JBoss 7.1.1 is not JPA 2.1 compliant and Hibernate 4.3.4 uses JPA 2.1, so the maximum version of Hibernate a JBoss 7.1.1 can support is the 4.2.11.

I'm moving my application to a Wildfly 8 server which already has the latest Hibernate version on it.